# Finding record by recordId and userId while updating a value inside array, using Mongose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm sorry if the title is a bit confusing, but I'm not sure how to re-phrase it.

So I have the following object:

```
{
    "_id": "622dec2e037d7ae286b366c9",
    "name": "Moriel Odeski",
    "email": "moriel96@gmail.com",
    "street": "Ben Gurion",
    "city": "Be'er Sheva",
    "zipcode": 329886,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Test",
            "completed": true
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Test2",
            "completed": false
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "Test3",
            "completed": false
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "title": "Do The Dishes",
            "completed": false
        }
    ],
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "That's Moriel's Post",
            "body": "According to my evaluations 0-0"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Something about something",
            "body": "That's interesting"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to write a function that gets a `userID` and a `taskID` and by calling it, it changes the `.completed` of the task to `true` where `id = taskID` and where `userId : userID`

I have the following function that doesn't work:

```
const markTaskCompleted = (userID , taskID) =>
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        User.findOneAndUpdate({id : userID , tasks : {$elemMatch: {id : taskID}}},
            {$set: {"tasks.$.completed" : true}},
            {"new" : true , "safe" : true , "upsert" : true} , function(err , data)
            {
                if(err){reject(err)}
                else
                {
                    resolve(data.tasks)
                }
            })
    })
}
```

It throws :

```
Plan executor error during findAndModify :: caused by :: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
```

Where did I go wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

I feel difficult to read your code because it doesn't look clean..
so maybe first it's better to make it cleaner.. I guess?

```js
const markTaskCompleted = async (userID , taskID) => await User.findOneAndUpdate({
    id: userID, 
    tasks: {$elemMatch: {id: taskID}}
  },
  {$set: {"tasks.$.completed": true}},
  {"new": true , "safe": true , "upsert": true}, 
})
```

You used callback inside callback so it didn't look clean to me.
I used `async/await`. I hope this looks cleaner to you too.

The official mongoose document also uses `await` for `findOneAndUpdate()` method.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html#getting-started

Check it out.
Can you check if the code I wrote works?